# TSQL Price Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Im after some assistance on how to pivot the following data. I have a pricing table like the following example.a

It contains products with varying pricing information on Qty Breaks. What I need to do is take this data and pivot into the table. The database is hosted in MSSQL-2012

example.a

```
ProductId Qty Price Reference
---------+---+-----+-------------
3         1   18.92 
3         1   4.65  
3         24  3.72  
3         72  3.45  
3         1   3.40  Quote:11223344
---------+---+-----+-------------
```

Additionally:

When pivoting the table, if there are products with the same Qty, pick the lowest price. As Shown above, ProductID 3 has 3x rows of pricing where they have the same Qty. So the pivot must only select and show the lowest rate

Required Pivot Result

```
ProductId Qty1 Price1 Reference1      Qty2 Price2  Reference2    Qty2 Price2  Reference2
---------+----+------+---------------+----+------+--------------+----+------+-------------
3         1     3.4   Quote:11223344  24    3.72             72   3.45
---------+----+------+---------------+----+------+--------------+----+------+-------------
```

Really would appreciate some ideas on who to tackle such a Query

thanks

Comment: `Select ..., min(Price) ... Group by ProductId, Qty` first in a CTE and then do your pivot on that subquery.

Comment: Do you know how many different `Quantity` rows you'll have?  SQL Server supports `PIVOT`, but you can't supply a dynamic number of result columns.  You either have to explicitly list them (say, "give me the greatest 3 quantities"), or construct your query with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi,
They are dynamic QTY's. So yes this will be an issue. Appreciate the responses.